# Changing bg color of div vs. Text

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I attempt to dynamically change the color of text via on click I seem to have no problem using style.color="___" however, this doesn't seem to want to work for the background color of divs.  Is there a particular reason for this?

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");

var square = document.getElementById("square");

text.onclick = function() {
  if (this.style.color === "blue") {
    this.style.color = "black";
    console.log("it worked");
  } else {
    this.style.color = "blue";
  }
};

square.onclick = function() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor === "#ccc") {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
  }
};
```

```css
#text {
  color: blue;
}
#square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Test</p>

<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Basic debugging: `console.log()` the backgroundColor before you test it with `===`.

Comment: `this.style.backgroundColor = x` should work, provided `this` is a valid element.

Comment: `this.style.backgroundColor` is equal to `rgb(204, 204, 204)` (in Chrome)

Comment: `console.log(this.style.backgroundColor)`

Comment: @Chris — There is code in the question. You can see that `this` is a valid element and (with a bit of debugging) that `this.style.backgroundColor = x` does work.

Comment: @Quentin, I didn't run the code when I made the comment because there wasn't a runnable code. You edited the OP and made it runnable just after. But yeah, I see that now.

Comment: When I debugged the color it returned an empty " " which means no value yes?  Also someone below noted that typing this.style.backgrouncColor looks for in line and then falls into the else condition, how do IO direct it to look at the css vs. the inl;ine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with your code:

1. When checking an element's `style` definition, you are looking for inline styles, not styles stored in CSS. That's why the link text doesn't change from blue to black on the first click, it's actually falling into the `else` condition first and then setting an inline style to blue. After the first click, an inline style has been set and the clicking works correctly.
2. You are checking for `#ccc` but the browser is converting this to an *inline* style of `rgb(204, 204, 204)` - so you are actually checking if `#ccc` is equal to `rgb(204, 204, 204)`, which they are not, thus your color never changes.

To check an element's styles including styles defined in stylesheets, you can use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
window.getComputedStyle(square,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

You're probably better off using classes for the different colors rather than checking inline styles. You can create semantic names for your classes and switch to different colors as needed without needing to check specific CSS values in JavaScript.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var square = document.getElementById("square");

text.onclick = function() {
  if (this.className === "text-blue") {
    this.className = 'text-black';
  } else {
    this.className = "text-blue";
  }
};

square.onclick = function() {
  if (this.className === "square-grey") {
    this.className = "square-white";
  } else {
    this.className = "square-grey";
  }
};
```

```css
#text.text-blue {
  color: blue;
}

#text.text-black {
  color: black;
}

#square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#square.square-grey {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#square.square-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p id="text" class="text-blue">Test</p>

<div id="square" class="square-grey"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Very interesting.  So how do I direct it to look at the css styler rather than the inline style?  Also when I debug via the console i simply get empty " "

Comment: I've edited my answer to include getting all CSS values. Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner see my edits where the colors are kept defined in CSS as classes and in JavaScript you merely switch the class that is being used.

Comment: Right but getting this computed style doesn't actually make the way I call the element any differently.  If for example I'm looking for height and the style returns 100px, and I further go if(style.height == "100px") won't that still be initially looking at the inline?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Yes, that's right. When you use `element.style` you are always looking at the element's *inline styles*. So instead of that, you either need to store the styles in classes as shown in my above code snippet, or you would need to use `getComputedStyle()` like `if (window.getComputedStyle(square, null).getPropertyValue('height') == '100px')`. Or you would always need to make sure that you have inline styles on the tags in your HTML code.

Comment: Oh I see!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

style returns for your backgroundColor to **rgb(204, 204, 204)** and expects and rgb value

Answer (score 0):

Your java script returning colour in rgb format (backgroundColor : rgb(204, 204, 204) ).

Below code will work :

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");

var square = document.getElementById("square");
$(document).ready(function() {
text.onclick = function() {
  if (this.style.color === "blue") {
    this.style.color = "black";
    console.log("it worked");
  } else {
    this.style.color = "blue";
  }
};

square.onclick = function() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(204, 204, 204)") {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
     console.log("div worked");
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
  }
};
  });
```

```css
#text {
  color: blue;
}
#square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text">Test</p>

<div id="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is JavaScript will set color as `rgb()` even if you give a `hex` value(in this case `#ccc`) to backgroundColor. There are two possible way to solve this

1. **Check for rgb() instead of hex**

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");

var square = document.getElementById("square");

text.onclick = function()
{
    if(this.style.color === "blue")
    {
        this.style.color = "black";
        console.log("it worked");
    } else
    {
        this.style.color = "blue";
    }
};

square.onclick = function()
{
    if(this.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(204, 204, 204)")
    {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    } else
    {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
    }
};
```

```css
#text
{
    color: blue;
}

#square
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Test</p>

<div id="square"></div>
```

2. **Convert the obtained rgb() color from `this.style.backgroundColor` to hex and check with `if`**

   Check here for that method [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)